# modal popup example mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to have a modal popup that may also have validation upon post.  Can I have an example please.

Comment: sure lots, look here http://awesome.codeplex.com, there's a link to live demo on the homepage

Comment: Check this:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093633/whats-the-best-way-to-call-a-modal-dialog-in-asp-net-mvc-using-twitter-bootstra/12843281#12843281][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093633/whats-the-best-way-to-call-a-modal-dialog-in-asp-net-mvc-using-twitter-bootstra/12843281#12843281

Answer (score 0):

For the validation piece, a great example is provided by good ole [Scott Gu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx). I would suggest using client-side validation (requires MVC 2) rather than validating on post. Follow Scott Gu's post precisely, and optionally swap out the microsoft .js files for jquery.validate.min.js and MicrosoftMvcJqueryValidation.js (only do this if you're like me and prefer using all jquery instead of mish-mash MS javascript).

For the modal dialog, I like [jqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/) but there are several plugins out there to choose from.

Comment: Isn`t there any example which include a modal dialog ?

Comment: I haven't found a good example; however, will know how to do it after reading the links I have posted above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered twitter bootstrap
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/
There's a whole section on modal
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals
The validation itself can done via jQuery.