# What's the best way to call a modal dialog in ASP.NET MVC using Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently using [Twitter's Bootstrap toolkit](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/#popovers) on a new project and I had a question on the best way to use the modal dialog in ASP.NET MVC3.

Is the best practice to have a Partial that contains the modal's markup and then use javascript to render that onto the page or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Here goes my little tutorial which demonstrates Twitter's Bootstrap (2.x) modal dialog that works with forms and partials in ASP.Net MVC 4.

To download similar project but targeting MVC 5.1 and Bootstrap 3.1.1 please [visit this site](http://www.fabro.pl/Download.aspx?S=Bootstrap%20modal%20MVC%205).

Start with an empty MVC 4 Internet template.

Add reference to Bootstrap using NuGet

In the App_Start/BundleConfig.cs add the following lines:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/bootstrap").Include(
                    "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                    "~/Content/bootstrap-responsive.css"));
```

In the Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml 
modify the @styles.Render line so it will look like:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css", "~/Content/themes/base/css",  "~/Content/bootstrap")
```

and the @Scripts.Render line:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery", "~/bundles/jqueryui",  "~/bundles/bootstrap")
```

So far we have Bootstrap prepared to work with MVC 4 so let's add a simple model class MyViewModel.cs to the /Models folder:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
    public class MyViewModel
    {
        public string Foo { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The bar is absolutely required")]
        public string Bar { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In the HomeController Add the following lines:

```
using MvcApplication1.Models;
//...

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return PartialView("_Create");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(MyViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                SaveChanges(model);
                return Json(new { success = true });
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", e.Message);
            }

        }
        //Something bad happened
        return PartialView("_Create", model);
    }


    static void SaveChanges(MyViewModel model)
    {
        // Uncommment next line to demonstrate errors in modal
        //throw new Exception("Error test");
    }
```

Create new Partial View in the Views/Home folder and name it _Create.cshtml:

```
@using MvcApplication1.Models
@model MyViewModel

<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Create Foo Bar</h3>
</div>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "modal-form" }))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary()

<div  class="modal-body">
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Foo)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Foo)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Foo)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Bar)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Bar)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Bar)
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Undo</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
</div>

}
```

In the Home/Index.cshtml remove the default content from the template and replace it with following:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<br />
<br />
<br />

@Html.ActionLink("Create", "Create", null, null, new { id = "btnCreate", @class = "btn btn-small btn-info" })

<div id='dialogDiv' class='modal hide fade in'>
    <div id='dialogContent'></div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        //Optional: turn the chache off
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

        $('#btnCreate').click(function () {
            $('#dialogContent').load(this.href, function () {
                $('#dialogDiv').modal({
                    backdrop: 'static',
                    keyboard: true
                }, 'show');
                bindForm(this);
            });
            return false;
        });
    });

    function bindForm(dialog) {
        $('form', dialog).submit(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.success) {
                        $('#dialogDiv').modal('hide');
                        // Refresh:
                        // location.reload();
                    } else {
                        $('#dialogContent').html(result);
                        bindForm();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    }

</script>
}
```

If you run your application, a nice Bootstrap modal will appear after clicking the Create button on the Home page.

Try to uncomment the `SaveChanges() //throw` line in HomeController.cs to prove that your controller handled errors will appear correctly in the dialog.

I hope that my sample clarifies a bit whole process of incorporating Bootstrap and creating modals in the MVC application.

Comment: zjerry, i used this method and it worked great. Is there an easy way so that multiple modals can be displayed on the same page. Essentially have a list of models each with a different id.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. However, am I the only one that has needed to a) add         $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
        if (form.valid()) {... in the form submit (to ensure that validation is done client-side) and b) following a server-side exception/model validation issue, unable to successfully bind the form again so that it fires an ajax post instead of a standard post?

Comment: Am wondering whether breakpoint at POST Create method should hit or not. It does not on my machine

Comment: Found the problem. If your "HTTPPOST" action is not called on pressing  "Save Changes" then see my mistake  http://stackoverflow.com/a/17472920/351708

Comment: I was trying to follow this example but with Bootstrap 3 and it just wouldn't work...well it might help some others knowing that if you have more than 1 form (I had 2 simply for testing the concept), then there is a change the submit would never trigger, the answer is to put it at the Document root level like so: `$(document).on('submit', '#yourFormId', function (e){ e.preventDefault(); }` and voila, it finally triggered!!! Gosh, so much time spent for 1 little trick.. oh I prefer to use the `e.preventDefault();` as it is more explicit...

Comment: I'm replying to an old thread here, but I can't get my dialog to show. It darkens the page I'm on like a dialog should be showing, but it never shows. I copied the code above exactly and put it in an existing controller. Any ideas?

Comment: I've prepared another sample updated to work with MVC5 and Bootstrap 3.1.1. [Here you can download](http://www.fabro.pl/Download.aspx?S=Bootstrap+modal+MVC+5) the project (C# VS2013).

Comment: @zjerry, I try to implement this in add mode to look up data in another table, but the result is page not found. Does modal could be called inside `@using (Html.BeginForm())`?

Comment: Good work, however because the FORM is loaded after document get ready, JQuery validation won't work, to fix this problem you need to change your JavaScript code: Change the function bindForm <code>$.validator.unobtrusive.parse('form');<code> on the first line.

Answer (score 2):

Great example,  I had to modify slightly for MVC 5 and Bootstrap 3.3.7, I changed the target div tags to the following, otherwise I was just getting the grey background and no modal dialog.  Hope this helps someone.

```
<div id='dialogDiv' class='modal fade' tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id='dialogContent'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Kevin Able , I also had to use this modification to get it working for me. Any ideas why or is this just due to later version of bootstrap i.e. 3.3.7?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @zjerry the solution is great but jQuery validation does not work, in order to fix you need to change the function bindForm as follow:

```
function bindForm(dialog) {
        $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('form');
        $('form', dialog).submit(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.success) {
                        $('#dialogDiv').modal('hide');
                        // Refresh:
                        // location.reload();
                    } else {
                        $('#dialogContent').html(result);
                        bindForm();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    }
```

Notice the first line of the function, because the form is loaded after jQuery validation was initialized.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on your design, but you should have a template for the modals.

On a single web app for example, you should have a template lying around that you would create a new instance from each time.

Usually on a normal website you would want to store this template inside a js creation function, so that you won't have to send the file to the user each time via http, and they can have it cached.

Comment: That's what I'm doing but I don't see an easy way to update the information in this template on the fly (without using angular/knockout)