# Twitter bootstrap modal does not load when integrating it in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I want to integrate Twitter bootstrap modal but when the index page loads when i click on the button modal does not load, I have taken the reference of [What's the best way to call a modal dialog in ASP.NET MVC using Twitter Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093633/whats-the-best-way-to-call-a-modal-dialog-in-asp-net-mvc-using-twitter-bootstra) . Please help to solve this issue, my code is written below.

MyViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MvcTwitterBootstrap.Models
{
    public class MyViewModel
    {
        public string Foo { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The bar is absolutely required")]
        public string Bar { get; set; }
    }
}
```

HomeController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MvcTwitterBootstrap.Models;

namespace MvcTwitterBootstrap.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return PartialView("_Create");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(MyViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    SaveChanges(model);
                    return Json(new { success = true });
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", e.Message);
                }

            }
            //Something bad happened
            return PartialView("_Create", model);
        }


        static void SaveChanges(MyViewModel model)
        {
            // Uncommment next line to demonstrate errors in modal
            //throw new Exception("Error test");
        }

    }
}
```

_Create.cshtml (PartialView)

```
@using MvcTwitterBootstrap.Models
@model MyViewModel

<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Create Foo Bar</h3>
</div>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "modal-form" }))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary()

<div class="modal-body">
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Foo)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Foo)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Foo)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Bar)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Bar)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Bar)
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Undo</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</button>
</div>

}
```

Index.cshtml

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
<script src="@Url.Content("~/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@Html.ActionLink("Create", "Create", null, null, new { id = "btnCreate", @class = "btn btn-small btn-info" })

<div id='dialogDiv' class='modal hide fade in'>
    <div id='dialogContent'></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        //Optional: turn the chache off
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });

        $('#btnCreate').click(function () {
            $('#dialogContent').load(this.href, function () {
                $('#dialogDiv').modal({
                    backdrop: 'static',
                    keyboard: true
                }, 'show');
                bindForm(this);
            });
            return false;
        });
    });

    function bindForm(dialog) {
        $('form', dialog).submit(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.success) {
                        $('#dialogDiv').modal('hide');
                        // Refresh:
                        // location.reload();
                    } else {
                        $('#dialogContent').html(result);
                        bindForm();
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your partial view is strongly typed to `MyViewModel` class. But in your `Create` action method, you are not passing an instance of your viewmodel to your partial view.

Try this

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
   var vm=new MyViewModel();        
   return PartialView("_Create",vm);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML snippet

```
<div id='dialogDiv' class='modal hide fade in'>
    <div id='dialogContent'></div>
</div>
```

Try removing the class 'hide' to make it

```
<div id='dialogDiv' class='modal fade in'>
    <div id='dialogContent'></div>
</div>
```

I found the when upgrading from Bootstrap v2 to v3 none of my existing modal's have shown until I removed the 'hide' class.

I haven't looked into it too much but I assume the JavaScript function no longer removes the hide class.

Comment: After removing the hide class when page loads there is one dialog box line displayed on the screen before pressing the button and after i press the button the dialog box loads properly but after if press dialog box undo or save button dialog box closes and my parent view where the button resides contains simple text of dialog.How this problem can be resolved, thanks for the above answer......

Comment: Create Foo Bar

The bar is absolutely required
Foo  
Bar   The bar is absolutely required
Undo  Save     .... This is the text that index view displays after closing the dialog box....

Comment: i found that after clicking on undo or save button the url changes to /Home/Create, how to correct this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Remove your action link and make it a button instead with data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dialogDiv" attributes.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dialogDiv">Create</button>
```

Remove your $('#btnCreate').click JS code. The bootstrap data attributes will handle showing and hiding the modal.

Load your Create partial with your Index view instead of using an Ajax call.

```
<div id='dialogDiv' class='modal hide fade in'>
    <div id='dialogContent'>@Html.Partial("~/{PathToView}/_Create.cshtml", new MyViewModel())</div>
</div>
```

Make sure you are loading the jquery-validate JS library.

Modify your Create controller action to return RedirectResult instead of JSON result on success:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```