# Open Partial View as Modal but without being static

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to open a modal window depending on which action the user is about to do.

[for example these actions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhL0b.jpg)

The markup looks like this:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Create", "User")'">Action</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Does anyone have an approach how to pop up a partial view depending if it is a crate action or any other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good reference how to marry MVC and modal forms. Basically it's based on what Azim suggested, but provides a full stack solution (i.e. explains how do you process errors, do stuff on the server, etc in details):

[What's the best way to call a modal dialog in ASP.NET MVC using Twitter Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093633/whats-the-best-way-to-call-a-modal-dialog-in-asp-net-mvc-using-twitter-bootstra)

Maybe your question is a duplicate of that one in fact.

Comment: This defenetly it! Thank you so  much!!!